# C# RS232 application do not work on ALL XP version(French )

Tags: visual-studio

I have made desktop application on VS2008 using vb.net & C# ,this work fine on English and chinese XP versions, but when customer run this application on French XP ver,this do not work properly.

Major functionality of this application is to communicate using RS232 protocol with device.
Application hang when communicating using RS232 on french XP.

SO i would like to know that how can make an application which can run on all XP OS.Regardless of any language XP

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you *certain* that the problem is related to language? Could it be something else specific to that machine? It seems unlikely that the UI language would affect the serial port.

Comment: i am not sure about it. bec do not have machine in my hand, this could be the possibility.So i want to reduce this risk factor wether that is by french XP or machine.

Comment: I suppose you could use an existing machine, install a French XP on it, and see whether you can reproduce the problem.